# Proving topologist's sine curve limit points.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I am not sure if this makes sense or not.

I was trying to prove that $\{0\} \times [-1,1]$ is a subset of the set of limit points of the topologist's sine curve. The topologist's sine curve being $S=\{(x,\sin\frac{1}{x})|x \in (0,1)\}$. I was wondering if this approach is ok. I tried to show if $y$ is fixed in $[-1,1]$, then there is a sequence of points $x_n \rightarrow 0$, such that any open ball around $(x_n,y)$ intersects $S$ for each positive epsilon, and natural number $N$. Here was my attempt:

Because of the rapid oscillations of $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ near $0$, consider the points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the form $(0,y), y \in [-1,1]$.I will try to show there is a sequence $x_n$ of points converging to $0$, such that for a fixed $y \in[-1,1]$, and each point in the sequence, every neighborhood of $(x_n,y)$ is contained in an open ball, that intersects the set $S$. For each $n \in\mathbb{N}$ let $\epsilon_n>0$ be an arbitrary small positive number.By the archimedean property choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$  such that $n \geq N \implies \frac{1}{2\pi n}<\epsilon_{n}$. Then for each $\epsilon_n>0$,choose a point  $x_n \in [\frac{1}{2 \pi(n+1)},\frac{1}{2 \pi n})$, as a term in the sequence. Then  for $n \geq N$,  $B((x_n,y),\epsilon_n) \cap S \neq \varnothing$. Since $\text{lim}x_n=0,B((0,y),\epsilon) \cap S \neq \varnothing$ for any positive $\epsilon$.

Comment: looks fine to me

Comment: I am having a bit of trouble understanding your second paragraph. Can you proof-read for accidental errors?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(0,p) \in \{0\} \times [-1,1]$. Find some $\alpha_0 \in [0, 2\pi]$ such that $\sin(\alpha_0)=p$. Note that this means that $\sin(\alpha_0 + 2n\pi) = p$ for all $n \in \Bbb N^+$ as well, by periodicity.

Then $x_n = (\frac{1}{\alpha_0 + 2n\pi} ,p)$ is a sequence that lies on $\mathcal{S}$ and converges to $(0,p)$. So $(0,p) \in \overline{\mathcal{S}}$

No need for vagueness about "rapid oscillations".

Answer (score 0):

"Rapid oscillations of $\sin 1/x$ near $0$" is not a rigorous argument. How do you demonstrate $B_\epsilon((x_n,y))\cap S\ne\emptyset\forall\epsilon>0$?

---

Let $y\in[-1,1]$. Consider any basis element $B_\delta((0,y))$. Now, $0<x<\delta\implies1/\delta<1/x<\infty$ and $\sin\left(\left(\frac1\delta,\infty\right)\right)=[-1,1]$, implying that there exists $x_1\in(0,\delta)$ such that $\sin(1/x_1)=y$. So $(x_1,y)\in S\cap B_\delta((0,y))$ and $(x_1,y)\ne(0,y)$. This completes the proof.